# what could I be missing in my typo3 extension to cause a table does not exist error?

Tags: typo3

I am getting this error after adding to an extension a class from another extension:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
#1247602160: Table 'deva.tx_bingoprizes_domain_model_hall' doesn't exist: SELECT tx_bingoprizes_domain_model_hall.* FROM tx_bingoprizes_domain_model_hall WHERE tx_bingoprizes_domain_model_hall.uid IN ('0') LIMIT 1 

Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Storage_Exception_SqlError thrown in file
/home/typo3_src/typo3_src-4.5.32/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php in line 1008.
```

The class added is tx_bingoprizes_domain_model_hall  which should be reading from the table tx_bpscore_domain_model_hall  as I added to the setup file:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
   Tx_Bingoprizes_Domain_Model_Hall {
        mapping {
            tableName = tx_bpscore_domain_model_hall
        }
   }
}
```

as I did for other extension which also reuses this class and which works properly ( I use it as my model for how to do this and as near as I can tell did everything the same way ). Why is typo3 still trying to use table tx_bingoprizes_domain_model_hall?  where else do I need to specify the other table?  I tried restarting the server, clearing caches, reinstalling the extension but still get the error.

I am using the latest 4.5 typo3.

Thanks

Comment: OK, I got it.    
   Once again I had forgotten to INCLUDE the necessary item (in this case bingoprizes) to the page's template.   So the error was not in my extension but in the typo3 config for the page.   
   I hate that, forget it all the time, it is counter-intuitive to me as I find it natural to assume the setup.txt stuff is auto included on any page that uses my extension.

Comment: btw, I decided to leave this question up as I know I will make the same mistake again and will end up here looking for answers.

Comment: If you found a solution to your own question, please add it as an answer, not a comment. Also mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to reiterate my comment as the answer...

OK, I got it. Once again I had forgotten to INCLUDE the necessary item (in this case bingoprizes) to the page's template. So the error was not in my extension but in the typo3 config for the page. I hate that, forget it all the time, it is counter-intuitive to me as I find it natural to assume the setup.txt stuff is auto included on any page that uses my extension.